# Visitor information collect

Tags: laravel-5

I try to collect visitor who click the link, information in db. I wrote some codes to collect these information . But it doesn't work properly. Below is my part of codes

```
public function getPostById($id)
    {
        $promo = Post::where('id', $id)->where('state', 'pending')->get();
        return view('single-promo', ['guest_promos' => $promo]);

        $visitor_info = new Visitor();
        $visitor_info->increments('click_count');
        $visitor_info->ip = Request::ip();
        $visitor_info->uri = Request::getRequestUri();
        $visitor_info->post_id = $id;
        $visitor_info->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything after the return statement will not run! you need to use middleware if you want to run code after the controller finsh.

see the docs for [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware) and [Terminable Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#terminable-middleware)